# const vector reference arguments in c++

Tags: c++, vector, constants, pass-by-reference

I consider myself fairly knowledgeable regarding the more basic aspects of C++, but sometimes I tend to get confused. I'm trying to implement a pair of functions that act on instances of `std::vector` and do some operations with their values, without changing them in-place. Naturally, I thought that a pass by `const&` would be  a reasonable thing to do. However, the following MWE fails to compile, and I would like to understand why:

```
#include<vector>

void func1(const std::vector<const char* const>& v){
     // do stuff
}

void func2(const std::vector<const std::vector<const char* const> >& v){
  for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i){
    func1(v[i]);
  }
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

The error message looks somewhat like this:

```
In file included from...include/c++/4.9.3/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from...include/c++/4.9.3/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from...include/c++/4.9.3/vector:61,
                 from test.cxx:2:
.../ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<const std::vector<const char* const> >’:
.../bits/allocator.h:92:11:   required from ‘class std::allocator<const std::vector<const char* const> >’
.../ext/alloc_traits.h:172:53:   required from ‘struct __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<const std::vector<const char* const> > >’
.../bits/stl_vector.h:75:28:   required from ‘struct std::_Vector_base<const std::vector<const char* const>, std::allocator<const std::vector<const char* const> > >’
.../bits/stl_vector.h:214:11:   required from ‘class std::vector<const std::vector<const char* const> >’
test.cxx:9:18:   required from here
.../ext/new_allocator.h:93:7: error: ‘const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const std::vector<const char* const>; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const std::vector<const char* const>*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const std::vector<const char* const>&]’ cannot be overloaded
       address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
.../ext/new_allocator.h:89:7: error: with ‘_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = const std::vector<const char* const>; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = const std::vector<const char* const>*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = const std::vector<const char* const>&]’
       address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
.../ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘class __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<const char* const>’:
.../bits/allocator.h:92:11:   required from ‘class std::allocator<const char* const>’
.../ext/alloc_traits.h:172:53:   required from ‘struct __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<const char* const> >’
.../bits/stl_vector.h:75:28:   required from ‘struct std::_Vector_base<const char* const, std::allocator<const char* const> >’
.../bits/stl_vector.h:214:11:   required from ‘class std::vector<const char* const>’
test.cxx:10:14:   required from here
.../ext/new_allocator.h:93:7: error: ‘const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const char* const; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const char* const*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const char* const&]’ cannot be overloaded
       address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
.../ext/new_allocator.h:89:7: error: with ‘_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = const char* const; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = const char* const*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = const char* const&]’
       address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
```

I'm confused by the fact that the error message claims that something cannot be overloaded, referring to the call of `func1` inside `func2`. It seems like there's an issue with resolving the `const` reference to the vector entry, but I really don't understand why this piece of code does not compile. I'm happy for any explanation, suggestion, or pointer to documentation about this type of behavior.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<const char* const>
```

You are trying to instantiate a vector with a `const` type.  The type needs to be at least *moveable*, and that isn't.  Change to:

```
std::vector<const char*>
```

instead

Comment: @nwp: Yes, I meant move-assignable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this does not really solve the problem, because the error in `func2` still persists. I need to remove the `const` also from the inner vector in the header of `func2` for it to compile successfully.

Comment: Well yes.  I meant "where-ever you have a vector of `char const * const` change it".

Answer (score 3):

The compiler reports *its* problem correctly, if you just know beforehand what that means.

The `std::allocator` has two overloads for `address`.

```
address(reference __x)
address(const_reference __x)
```

The problem for the compiler is that for a template type `const T`, the two types `T&` and `const T&` will be the same type. And then it believes that there are two copies of the same overload.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But how an I avoid this issue?

Comment: Ah ha!  So if you create your own allocator which just has one of the overloads, then you could use that as the allocator for your vector, and it would all work swimmingly!

Comment: @carsten : Just use the non-const type in the vector: `char const *` rather than `char const * const`.

Comment: It seems I also have to change this `const std::vector<const std::vector<const char*> >&` to this `const std::vector<std::vector<const char*> >&`